# react-native-core-ml-image - "CoreMLImage" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, coreml

I'm new in react-native :)
I'm trying to implement "react-native-core-ml-image": "0.0.6" with ios
tried with expo, get "CoreMLImage" was not found in the UIManager, when trying to solve it get new errors...

for now i created "react-native init" and still get the same error
can someone help me with this issue? will be very happy

didn't change in package.json or podfile, just runned with xcode build,
which was successful and "ios": "react-native run-ios --device 'myiPhone'

Comment: Please show the errors.